# Update/Notify other fragment in fragmenPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have multiple fragments inside FragmentPagerAdapter and I need to update the other fragments based upon operation performed on particular fragment. how should I do it

Answer (score 0):

Use local broadcast/ Eventbus to send notification to particular fragment.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: but it would require broadcast Receiver I need to pass between fragments. Am i missing something here??

Comment: Yes you need to register local broadcast receiver in your fragment to receive broadcast.

Comment: Check out this tutorial for more details http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/